# Count started conversations in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
+--------+------+----------+  
| fromId | toId | messages | 
+--------+------+----------+  
|     10 |    2 |  'text'  |
|     10 |    4 |  'text'  |  
|      4 |   10 |  'text'  |
|      5 |   10 |  'text'  |
|      5 |   10 |  'text'  |  
|     10 |    3 |  'text'  |  
|      6 |   10 |  'text'  |  
+--------+------+----------+
```

Every row is a **message** from fromId to toId.
As you can see I have 5 conversations in which user whose ID is 10 is involved:
10 with 2
10 with 4
10 with 5
10 with 3
10 with 6
How can I count them in a Select query??
I have tried this one:

```
SELECT * FROM messaggi WHERE fromId = 10 OR toID = 10 GROUP BY (fromId)
```

but something tells me that I have to try a SELECT from another SELECT, I think it's called a subquery.

Comment: Wait... So, `5, 10` is just one? Yea, got it. You have a wrong structure. It shouldn't be that way.

Comment: To be true I didn't write in the example the other columns (messages and timestamp)

Comment: Go on. Try something.

Comment: @Strawberry what do you mean?

Comment: He's asking you what have you tried already.

Comment: I have improved my question, admitting it was a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

So we need to find the total number of distinct conversations in any direction. What we can do is query the results and union them together but switch the columns around for one of the queries. This gives us all results for conversations in any direction. We then can count the distinct results to find out how many conversations there are for an individual.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT *) FROM
    (SELECT fromId as col1, toId as col2 FROM conversations WHERE fromId = 10
       UNION
     SELECT toId as col1, fromId as col2 FROM conversations WHERE toId = 10)
```

Comment: `DISTINCT *` is not ok

Answer (score 0):

The answer is equal to the number of rows returned by this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT from_id x FROM my_table WHERE to_id = 10
 UNION
SELECT DISTINCT to_id x FROM my_table WHERE from_id = 10;
```

Comment: The count is equal to the size of the array.

Comment: This is ok, no problem for the count.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand `10, 5` is the same as `5, 10` so doesnt matter who start the conversation, so:

**[SQL DEMO](http://rextester.com/ILD29677)**

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT 
            LEAST(`fromId`, `toId`) AS a,
            GREATEST(`fromId`, `toId`) AS b
      FROM Table1
      WHERE 10 in (`fromId`, `toId`)
     ) T
```

Comment: This assumes that user 10 is involved in all conversations.

Comment: @Strawberry Didnt saw that condition, the sample query wasnt there when I start. But already fix

Comment: Well, to be fair, you're interpretation might be the right one; the question is a bit vague

Comment: What if it was `1`?

Comment: what you mean 1? instead of 10?

Comment: It's ok, I have improved my question. What if I want to know the number of conversations form each user i.e. instead of hard writing user 10, I want to select user id form another table (users) and get conversations involving each id?

Comment: instead of `10` you  can use a  variable `@userID` and set it before the query `SET @userID = 10`  or `SELECT INTO @userID  userField FROM anotherTable`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to change the way it is constructed. Have one table for threads:

```
TID
---
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
```

And now, each thread can have any (right now 2) number of participants. So, let's have participants table.

```
TID | UID
----+----
 1  | 10
 1  |  2
 2  | 10
 2  |  4
 3  |  4
 3  | 10
 4  |  5
 4  | 10
 5  |  5
 5  | 10
 6  | 10
 6  |  3
 7  |  6
 7  | 10
```

Now, if you find the count of the participated ones, in a distinct way:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(GROUP_CONCAT(`UID` ORDER BY `UID` ASC)) FROM participants GROUP BY `TID`
```

You get this:

[image: preview]

And finally, wrapping it with `COUNT` gives you `5`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT DISTINCT(GROUP_CONCAT(`UID` ORDER BY `UID` ASC)) FROM `participants` GROUP BY `TID`) AS T
```

[image: count]

Comment: now that I have improved my question do you think your design is better? From which point of view? I don't need more participants since is a one to one message system

Comment: @Ferex it would be scalable buddy... Something like these operations are easily doable. I suggest taking this approach. Really!